# Raspberry Pi MAX31865 Python to Java conversion

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I'm trying to convert a piece of Python code reading MAX13865 sensor into Java. The Python code works well and return an expected number (1238), while the Java version always returns 32767. To simplify the reading I reduced the Python code and the Java code to the smallest. The Python code below still works very well. What am I missing? It seems to be very simple, but still doesn't work...

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import math

class MAX31865(object):

    def __init__(self, cs_pin, clock_pin, data_in_pin, data_out_pin, board = GPIO.BCM):

        self.cs_pin = cs_pin
        self.clock_pin = clock_pin
        self.data_in_pin = data_in_pin
        self.data_out_pin = data_out_pin
        self.board = board

        # Initialize needed GPIO
        GPIO.setmode(self.board)
        GPIO.setup(self.cs_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.clock_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.data_in_pin, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.data_out_pin, GPIO.OUT)

        # Pull chip select high to make chip inactive
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)

    def get_data(self):
        '''Acqures raw RDT data.'''
        self.address = int(0x01)    #RTD MSBs
        MSB = self.read()
        self.address = int(0x02)    #RTD LSBs
        LSB = self.read()
        MSB = MSB<<8
        raw = MSB+LSB
        raw = raw>>1
        return raw

    def read(self):
        '''Reads 16 bits of the SPI bus from a self.address register & stores as an integer in self.data.'''
        bytesin = 0

        # Select the chip
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        # Assert clock bit
        GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.LOW)

        # Write to address
        for i in range(8):
            bit  = self.address>>(7 - i)
            bit = bit & 1
            GPIO.output(self.data_out_pin, bit)
            GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.LOW)

        # Read in 8 bits
        for i in range(8):
            GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            bytesin = bytesin << 1
            if (GPIO.input(self.data_in_pin)):
                bytesin = bytesin | 1
            GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        # Dsable clock
        GPIO.output(self.clock_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        # Unselect the chip
        GPIO.output(self.cs_pin, GPIO.HIGH)

        # Save data
        self.data = bytesin
        return self.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs_pin = 8
    clock_pin = 11
    data_in_pin = 9
    data_out_pin = 10

    # Configure RTDs
    rtd = MAX31865(cs_pin, clock_pin, data_in_pin, data_out_pin)
    log_string = ''

    # Run main loop
    running = True
    while(running):
        try:
            RTD_code = rtd.get_data()
            print '{:.0f}'.format(RTD_code * 4300 / 32768)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            running = False
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And my tentative of Java conversion:

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.Pin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;

public class MAX31865 {

  protected Pin cs_pin;
  protected Pin clock_pin;
  protected Pin data_in_pin;
  protected Pin data_out_pin;

  protected GpioPinDigitalOutput cs_pin_out;
  protected GpioPinDigitalOutput clock_pin_out;
  protected GpioPinDigitalInput data_in_pin_in;
  protected GpioPinDigitalOutput data_out_pin_out;

  protected int address;
  protected int data;
  final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

  public MAX31865(Pin cs_pin, Pin clock_pin, Pin data_in_pin, Pin data_out_pin, int address, int data) {
    this.cs_pin = cs_pin;
    this.clock_pin = clock_pin;
    this.data_in_pin = data_in_pin;
    this.data_out_pin = data_out_pin;
    this.address = address;
    this.data = data;

    // Initialize needed GPIO
    cs_pin_out       = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(cs_pin, "SPI_CS");
    clock_pin_out    = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(clock_pin, "SPI_CLCK");
    data_in_pin_in   = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(data_in_pin, "SPI_IN");
    data_out_pin_out = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(data_out_pin, "SPI_OUT");

    // Pull chip select high to make chip inactive
    cs_pin_out.setState(PinState.HIGH);
  }

  /**
   * Reads 16 bits of the SPI bus from an address register & stores as an integer in data.
   * @return
   * @throws InterruptedException 
   */
  public int read() throws InterruptedException {
    int bytesin = 0;

    // Select the chip
    cs_pin_out.setState(PinState.LOW);
    // Assert clock bit
    clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.LOW);

    // Write to address
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      byte bit = (byte) ((address >> (7 - i)) & 1);
      data_out_pin_out.setState(bit == 1);
      clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.HIGH);
      clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.LOW);
    }

    // Read in 8 bits
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.HIGH);
      bytesin = bytesin << 1;
      if (data_in_pin_in.getState() == PinState.HIGH) {
        bytesin = bytesin | 1;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Is low!");
      }
      clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.LOW);
    }

    // Disable Clock
    clock_pin_out.setState(PinState.HIGH);
    // Unselect the chip
    cs_pin_out.setState(PinState.HIGH);
    Thread.sleep(1);

    // Save data
    data = bytesin;
    return data;
  }

  public int getData() throws InterruptedException {
    address = 0x01;
    int msb = read();
    address = 0x02;
    int lsb = read();
    System.out.println(msb + " " + lsb);
    msb = msb << 8;
    int raw = msb + lsb;
    raw = raw >> 1;
    return raw;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    MAX31865 max = new MAX31865(RaspiPin.GPIO_08, RaspiPin.GPIO_11, RaspiPin.GPIO_09, RaspiPin.GPIO_10, (int)0x80, (int)0xC2);
    // max.write();
    while (true) {
      System.out.println(max.getData());
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

## Update

Just adding one comment in case it can help others. If you power-off the system (and so the MAX31865) it will stop working back until you WRITE to it.

```
    # Configure RTDs
    rtds = []
    address = int(0x80)    # RTD control register, see datasheet for details
    data =  int(0xC2)      # RTD condrol register data, see datasheet for details
    for cs_pin in cs_pins:
        rtds.append(MAX31865(cs_pin, clock_pin, data_in_pin, data_out_pin, address, data))
    print rtds
    for rtd in rtds:
        rtd.write()
    print rtd
```

Comment: Could you please check the values read (`msb`, `lsb`, `MSB`, `LSB`) in `get_data`?

Comment: In the java version, I get 255 for both msb and lsb. In the Python version I get 75 and 69 (For a result being 1264 which is 68.22C)

Comment: Hm, ok. Then please check the value `bit` in each iteration when writing the adress and `bytesin` while you are doing the bit shifting. Is the adress correct?

Comment: In Python:
[code]
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
2
6
14
30
60
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
2
6
14
28
56
[code]
In Java:
[code]
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
2
6
14
30
60
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
2
6
14
28
56
[code]
The addresses seems to be fine, but the reads seems to be wrong...

Comment: when I print GPIO.input(self.data_in_pin) I get this: 0
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
And for Java:
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: Could you please try to read from another adress just to see if you can read any zeros at all? I had a look at the datasheet and you could try Configuration (00h) or Fault Status (07h).

Comment: Tried addresses from 0 to 7 (included) and they all return only 1 for every single bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to the way Pi4J maps the GPIO pin numbers vs the Python version.

https://www.pi4j.com/1.2/pins/model-3b-rev1.html

The Python version:

```
MAX31865(8, 11, 9, 10)
```

And the java equivalent:

```
MAX31865 max = new MAX31865(RaspiPin.GPIO_10, RaspiPin.GPIO_14, RaspiPin.GPIO_13, RaspiPin.GPIO_12);
```

Notice that the pin numbers are different. But both give the exact same result now. Everything else works just fine.

RTFM :(

Comment: As usual...You think you did something wrong in the smart stuff you were doing. But it is just some stupid thing you overlooked in the beginning. Been there ;)